# Ubuntu stuck while installing - only wallpaper and cursor appear on desktop

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop using live USB.

I go to my boot menu and select my pendrive. The Ubuntu logo appears and I hear a sound like the login screen sound, and then the wallpaper and mouse cursor appear, and nothing else happens.

My PC configuration is:

- Core 2 duo 2.93 GHz processor
- 4GB DDR2 RAM
- 1GB Nvdia graphics card
- 500 GB HDD
- Intel 41RQ motherboard

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core problem is that you indicated that it gets to the desktop screen, but then 'hangs', and doesn't do anything after the logon sound triggers.

When booting from a LiveUSB or a LiveCD/DVD, the speed of reading data into memory from those devices is *far slower* than if it were actually installed on the hard drive.  Older systems had USB 1.1/2.0, which is far slower than USB 3.0/3.1 or Lightning/USB-C.  As a result, it can sometimes take a *long time* to actually load the desktop screen.

My suggestion is to wait.  If it takes over an hour to actually load the Live environment desktop screen or installer prompt, then you should be worried.  (From your comments however it took maybe 25 minutes, which is not atypical for older machines trying to run standard Ubuntu).